# Puzzle with numbers you have to add up to get given numbers? Can't remember the name

Tags: puzzle-identification

Basically what that title says. I remember a puzzle that had a white area in no specific shape that would give you large numbers on the outside and you have to fill in the boxes with numbers that add up to the large number, and you have to fill in the whole grid. Does anyone know what this is called? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Kakuro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakuro) puzzles. Here's an example of one, both unsolved and solved:

[image: unsolved kakuro puzzle] [image: solved kakuro puzzle]

Comment: Amazing thank you! I haven't seen one of these in a long time and I wanted to try it out, thanks!